# GDB hangs forever on Solaris

Tags: solaris, exec, fork, gdb

GDB seems to hang everytime when I try `run` command from gdb prompt. When I ran `ps`, there are two gdb processes that have been spawned and pstack reveals the following -

```
15:47:02:/home/stufs1/pmanjunath/a2/Asgn2_code$ uname -a
SunOS compserv1 5.10 Generic_118833-24 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Blade-1500

15:44:04:/home/stufs1/pmanjunath/a2/Asgn2_code$ ps aux | grep gdb
pmanjuna 13121  0.1  0.1 1216  968 pts/23   S 15:44:11  0:00 grep gdb
pmanjuna 13077  0.0  0.1 7616 4392 pts/15   S 15:41:41  0:00 gdb client
pmanjuna 13079  0.0  0.1 7616 4392 pts/15   T 15:41:51  0:00 gdb client

15:44:50:/home/stufs1/pmanjunath/a2/Asgn2_code$ pstack 13077
13077:  gdb client
 fef42c30 vfork    ()
 00065938 procfs_create_inferior (32ea10, 32d728, 317430, 1, 0, 657a8) + 190
 0008c668 sol_thread_create_inferior (32ea10, 32d728, 317430, 1, 25e030, 0) + 18
 000ffda0 find_default_create_inferior (32ea10, 32d728, 317430, 1, 405c, 4060) + 20
 000d8690 run_command_1 (0, 1, 32ea10, 1, ffbff0f4, 316fd0) + 208
 0007e344 do_cfunc (316fd0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0) + c
 0008016c cmd_func (316fd0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0) + 30
 0004c1d4 execute_command (316fd0, 1, 0, 4f00c, 1, 2dc800) + 390
 000eb6a0 command_handler (2f4ee0, 0, 2f3800, 8acf, ff000000, ff0000) + 8c
 000ebbcc command_line_handler (2f3800, 7200636c, 32d71c, 7200, 2dfc00, 2dfc00) + 2a4
 0019b354 rl_callback_read_char (fef6b6f8, 0, 931d8, 0, fef68284, fef68284) + 340
 000eafb4 rl_callback_read_char_wrapper (0, fef709b0, 0, 11, 0, eafb0) + 4
 000eb590 stdin_event_handler (0, 0, 932b4, fef6fad4, 0, 1) + 60
 000ea780 handle_file_event (1, 1084, 932f4, 4f00c, ff1f2000, 1000) + bc
 000ea11c process_event (0, 0, ffffffff, 0, 2df9f8, 0) + 84
 000ea9d4 gdb_do_one_event (1, 1, 0, 2f3158, ff1f2000, 2) + 108
 000e7cd4 catch_errors (ea8cc, 0, 2473a8, 6, ffbff6f0, 1) + 5c
 000907e8 tui_command_loop (0, 64, ffffffff, 0, 0, 2f6190) + e0
 000e7fcc current_interp_command_loop (800000, ff400000, ffc00000, 800000, 0, 331b40) + 54
 00045b80 captured_command_loop (1, 1, 0, fef33a54, ff1f2000, 2) + 4
 000e7cd4 catch_errors (45b7c, 0, 22db20, 6, 2dc400, 0) + 5c
 0004625c captured_main (2d1800, 2f4ae0, 0, 0, 0, 0) + 6a0
 000e7cd4 catch_errors (45bbc, ffbffc18, 22db20, 6, 0, 0) + 5c
 00046bb0 gdb_main (ffbffc18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) + 24
 00045b6c main     (2, ffbffc9c, ffbffca8, 2f45b8, ff1f0100, ff1f0140) + 28
 000459dc _start   (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) + 5c

15:45:38:/home/stufs1/pmanjunath/a2/Asgn2_code$ pstack 13079
13079:  gdb client
 fef4098c execve   (ffbfffe6, ffbffc9c, ffbffca8)
 feec4a7c execlp   (ffbffdc6, ffffffff, 289bc0, ffbfed18, 0, ffbfed10) + ac
 0016e3e8 fork_inferior (32ea10, 32d728, 317430, 6567c, 653dc, 0) + 310
 00065938 procfs_create_inferior (32ea10, 32d728, 317430, 1, 0, 657a8) + 190
 0008c668 sol_thread_create_inferior (32ea10, 32d728, 317430, 1, 25e030, 0) + 18
 000ffda0 find_default_create_inferior (32ea10, 32d728, 317430, 1, 405c, 4060) + 20
 000d8690 run_command_1 (0, 1, 32ea10, 1, ffbff0f4, 316fd0) + 208
 0007e344 do_cfunc (316fd0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0) + c
 0008016c cmd_func (316fd0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0) + 30
 0004c1d4 execute_command (316fd0, 1, 0, 4f00c, 1, 2dc800) + 390
 000eb6a0 command_handler (2f4ee0, 0, 2f3800, 8acf, ff000000, ff0000) + 8c
 000ebbcc command_line_handler (2f3800, 7200636c, 32d71c, 7200, 2dfc00, 2dfc00) + 2a4
 0019b354 rl_callback_read_char (fef6b6f8, 0, 931d8, 0, fef68284, fef68284) + 340
 000eafb4 rl_callback_read_char_wrapper (0, fef709b0, 0, 11, 0, eafb0) + 4
 000eb590 stdin_event_handler (0, 0, 932b4, fef6fad4, 0, 1) + 60
 000ea780 handle_file_event (1, 1084, 932f4, 4f00c, ff1f2000, 1000) + bc
 000ea11c process_event (0, 0, ffffffff, 0, 2df9f8, 0) + 84
 000ea9d4 gdb_do_one_event (1, 1, 0, 2f3158, ff1f2000, 2) + 108
 000e7cd4 catch_errors (ea8cc, 0, 2473a8, 6, ffbff6f0, 1) + 5c
 000907e8 tui_command_loop (0, 64, ffffffff, 0, 0, 2f6190) + e0
 000e7fcc current_interp_command_loop (800000, ff400000, ffc00000, 800000, 0, 331b40) + 54
 00045b80 captured_command_loop (1, 1, 0, fef33a54, ff1f2000, 2) + 4
 000e7cd4 catch_errors (45b7c, 0, 22db20, 6, 2dc400, 0) + 5c
 0004625c captured_main (2d1800, 2f4ae0, 0, 0, 0, 0) + 6a0
 000e7cd4 catch_errors (45bbc, ffbffc18, 22db20, 6, 0, 0) + 5c
 00046bb0 gdb_main (ffbffc18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) + 24
 00045b6c main     (2, ffbffc9c, ffbffca8, 2f45b8, ff1f0100, ff1f0140) + 28
 000459dc _start   (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) + 5c
```

Why are these processes hanging in `vfork` and `execve`? This happens on my university machine where fellow students also have accounts. None of them have reported this problem. Seems to happen only to me.

**EDIT** : With [schily's help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/237514/17829), I am able to corner the problem. When I log in, I am in `csh` by default. GDB works pretty fine here. Now, I run `bash` from `csh` to enter bash shell. Now GDB hangs. When I check the output of `echo $SHELL`, I see something strange

```
$ echo $SHELL
 /bin/bash=
```

There is an equal sign at the end of the output. I guess GDB is trying to spawn a bash shell I guess using the default shell variable and fails to find the binary cos of that equal sign. Now, the problem is to find out how that equal sign is getting into the shell path.

Comment: What is the output from the `env` command?  Do you have any `LD_*` environment variables set?  What's the output from `pmap` on your hung `gdb` processes?  Can you get a `pstack` of your client processes?  (Maybe by using the `-F` option?)

Comment: Also, check `/var/adm/messages` for errors - both `vfork()` and `execve()` are memory-intensive.  If you each have your own machines, maybe yours has a hardware problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process that calls `vfork()` hangs because it is the `vfork() parent` and the child did borrow the process image at that time so it cannot run until the child finishes a call to`_exit()` or `exec*()`.

So you need to find out why the exec*() hangs.

A typical reason for a hang in exec*() is a NFS hang or a traversal through a non-existent automount point.

Call `truss -p 13079` to get the path for the hanging exec*().

Comment: Good catch.  I missed the fact that the two processes are parent-child.  (And FWIW, this is just one reason why I don't like `vfork()`...).  And there's a good chance `truss` won't return any data in this case as it tracks system calls as they happen.  System calls aren't happening here as the processes are both hung, although a `truss -vall ...` on the child process might emit the arguments.

Comment: `truss` should return the file path in the first argument. You don't need the argv in clear text. BTW: `vfork()` is still a good idea to  increase performance. I could increase the Bourne Shell performance by 20% for `configure` just by replacing `fork()` for the simple commands by `vfork()`. I am currently working on using more `vfork() ` for pipes and then will be as fast as ksh93. For a debugger, it is not useful to use `vfork()` instead of `fork()`.

Comment: Your suspicion is somewhat right. As I soon as I run truss, GDB gets unstuck and says "Cannot exec /bin/bash=: No such file or directory". But truss says a different story "execve("/usr/local/bin/gdb", 0xFFBFFCAC, 0xFFBFFCB8) Err#2 ENOENT". And I confirmed this is not happening with csh only bash! Also /bin/bash is very much there

Comment: I cannot help you with `"Cannot exec /bin/bash=: No such file or directory"` you would need to check your environment (e.g. `PATH`)  to find a possible reason. `ENOENT` for `"/usr/local/bin/gdb"`is obviously a result from PATH name search that traversed a hung NFS mount or similar automopunt point.

Comment: @PavanManjunath - Do you have similar problems running any other utilities from `/usr/local/bin`?  Does `/bin/bash` exist?

Comment: @AndrewHenle /bin/bash does exist. Also when I say `which bash` it shows `/usr/bin/bash`. I verified the checksum of both binaries. They are the same. Another curious anomaly is "echo $SHELL" output. It says "/bin/bash=". Do you observe the `=` sign at the end? IN fact GDB also complained the same. I don't know how that `=` sign is sneaking into the shell path. Cos I am not setting $SHELL anywhere explicitly. I just say `bash` and enter bash shell.

Comment: So you have rubbish in $SHELL, I recommend to correct this.

Comment: @PavanManjunath You need to find out what's putting that value in $SHELL.  Look in files in your home directory for the SHELL value getting set.  The file you want to look at include `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login`, `.profile`, `.bashrc`, Also check any script those scripts run, if any.  An easy but not complete way to check is run `grep SHELL .*`.  That will miss looking at scripts the bash startup scripts call.  You'll get a lot of errors such as `grep: .ssh: Is a directory`.  You can ignore those, or if you don't want to see them you can run `grep SHELL .* 2>/dev/null` from a `bash` shell